# Writing and downloading a csv file using linq methods in c# is returning wrong data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, export-to-csv

In ASP.NET Core, I am using a Linq method to get my data from my `Prescriptions` table from the database, I am attempting to write that data to a csv file called `FutureFills.csv` in `wwwroot`, and download that file. Here is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/FutureFills")]
[Produces("text/csv")]
public IActionResult ExportFile()
{

    var futurefills = _context.Prescriptions
      .Where(f => f.FolderStatusId == 9)
      .Where(d => d.DeliveryDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
      .ToList();

    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    System.IO.StreamWriter write = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Stream);

    CsvFileDescription file = new CsvFileDescription 
    { 
        SeparatorChar = ',', FirstLineHasColumnNames = true 
    };

    return File(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(futurefills.ToString()), "text/csv", "FutureFills.csv");
}
```

So I have a button on a page that calls this action and downloads a csv file, it downloads and seems to work but when I open the csv file it is not the data that I need, I am expecting to get the `Prescriptions` table from my database, however I get this in the csv file

[image]

What am I doing wrong that it is not writing the correct data into the file?

Comment: Line 12-18 are not being used and can be deleted. You need to replace that with code that extracts the data as I've shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are simply outputting `futurefills.ToString()`, which is just outputting the name of the type of object it is holding.

Are you certain that `futurefills.ToString()` holds the value you are expecting ? Try debugging your application, and inpect the value of `futurefills` after the Linq-query.

You need to iterate over each element in the `futureFills` object, that you have seen contains to items. So you need to write a construct similar to this:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var row in futurefills)
{
    output.AppendLine(row.Field1 + ", " + row.Field2);
}
```

And then you can go ahead and `output.ToString()`

Something like this:

```
return File(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output.ToString()), "text/csv", "FutureFills.csv");
```

Comment: Well I have changed the `ToString()` to `ToList()` and I have tried running the program without it as well, however it gives me an error if I try anything else other than `ToString()`. I have a feeling that `ToString()` is wrong but I am unsure what to change it to.

Comment: Like doing `Object.ToString()` I just assumed that `ToString()` would help the data to be displayed, is this wrong?

Comment: Also if I remove`ToString()`, the error it gives me is `cannot convert from 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List<Foldersystem.models.Prescription>' to 'char[]'`

Comment: It is wrong if .ToString() is not overridden to perform whatever implementation that would output the data you are expecting. What you are seeing seems pretty normal behavior. Which is why I assume you are not debugging properly. You should set a break point, and inspect the value of futureFills, .. and if you are in Visual Studio, you can use Immediate Window to play around with how to get the data out.

Comment: Another useful tool you could use to develop queries with Linq is Linqpad https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: If you look at your output now, now you see it is outputting the List-object as ToString. What your should do is output each element of the list .. not the List object.

Comment: Yes when I debug and step into each line, I really just see that `futurefills` `count = 2`

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what approach you could use to get the data out. You need to adjust it to your fields of futurefills.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was unsure of how to append each field in `stringbuilder`. This is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You never executed the query. Add a `.ToList()` to the end of `futureFills`

```
    var futurefills = _context.Prescriptions
      .Where(f => f.FolderStatusId == 9)
      .Where(d => d.DeliveryDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: I added `ToList()` at the end of the query and it is still downloaded and displaying the same results

Comment: Can you update your question with the code change you made and a screen shot of the updated output result?

Comment: Yes I added the new code update, and my apologies, it gave me a different result in the csv file, I also added that in the edit.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're just doing `.ToString()` on a type and not on a string representation of the data. A common approach to exporting CSVs is to use a StringBuilder to create a string (comma separated) representation of the data you're dealing with.

Comment: Okay I see, but I thought that was what `CSvFileDescription` was for?

Comment: I don't even see you using it, only initializing it. Are you missing any code?

Comment: Thank you very much, the help was incredible!